# How to dump verilog compiled lines from a verilog file with many ifdef constructs?

Tags: verilog

```
Here is the requirement.
`define TYPE-1
    Line 1 ;
    Line 2;
    Line 3;
`define TYPE-2
   Line 4;
  Line 5;
 `endif
` define TYPE-3
  Line6
`else 
  Line 7 ;
Line 8
```

End of file.
 Requirement is to split the above Verilog file Master.v into 4 files that has only the content of `defines.
For ex = Above file Master.v should be split into 4 different Verilog files like below-

```
File-1.v :
                Line 1;
               Line 2;
              Line 3;

File-2.v:
  Line 4;
Line 5;

File-3.v:
  Line 6;

File-4.v:
   Line 7;
   Line 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

usually it is a compiler work. i.e. vcs can dump tokens which is what you ask for. On the other hand there are several verilog preprocessors around like vpp/vbpp
https://github.com/balanx/vbpp. You can find others on internet.